# Run gpedit.msc with "Run only specified Windows applications" enabled

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, application-launch, unwanted-application

```
win10_professional_6.1.7601
gpedit.msc accessible by default
```

> Are "program.msc" similar to "file.exe" and can GPO recognize msc-program launches? No. You have to find the executable that's associated with the program.msc
>
> Backup whole drives before changing permissions, because you don't want to find out you've hindered your PC without a fallback.

I want to setup certain applications to run using `gpedit.msc`. The idea that only the applications listed will run and that leaves Administrators having no way to re-open GPO to make any further changes. Is there any way to fallback a PC with GPO setting **"Run only specified Windows applications"** being enabled or undo what I did?

## PROBLEM

- How would I be able to run the **Local Group Policy Editor** (*gpedit.msc*) if "Run only specified Windows applications" is enabled?

## SOLUTION

- Include `mmc.exe` as one of the application(s) to be allowed to run

  - *mmc.exe* is associated with gpedit.msc

Answer (score 1):

[.msc](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/06/10/windows-msc-files-overview/) files are just text files containing XML. The extension .msc is associated with the application [`mmc.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mmc) (aka the [Microsoft Management Console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Management_Console)).

When you double-click, or shell-execute an msc file, windows will execute mmc.exe, passing in the .msc file as an argument. for instance, to run `secpol.msc`, windows will execute the command:

`"C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MMC.EXE" "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SECPOL.MSC" /S`

So, to your specific query about , `Run only specified Windows applications`, if you can run `mmc.exe`, that setting will not hinder you. Other settings may, like not having read access to the .msc file.